# AWS HTTPS certificate not working with load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate

I'm having a problem with setting up https.
Followed all the instructions in [aws](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-create-https-ssl-load-balancer.html#create-https-lb-console) and still shows up unsecure.

Security group has both ports open 443 and 80.

State of load balancer is active.

In the Route 53 Records the A records are pointed to the load balancer.

My website is linked from WIX.

Checked everything but couldnt manage to find out the problem.

Comment: are you forwarding http requests to https?

Comment: Well I setup everything and directed the A record to the load balancer but im getting 502 bad gateway.

Comment: Is your ssl certificate purchased from Wix or obtained from AWS CM?